# html 5 tags in html 4 transitional

Tags: performance, html, validation, browser

Do HTML 5 tags appearing in HTML 4 Transitional cause a performance issue? Will it validate?

Current doctype declaration:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

HTML 5 tags used:

`<section> <header> <nav>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do HTML 5 tags appearing in HTML 4 Transitional cause a performance issue?

No more so then if they appear in HTML 5.

> Will it validate?

No, of course not. They weren't added until HTML 5.

Comment: Sorry about accepting this answer 4 years later. I didn't receive any notifications.